# Finding last occurence of _sre.SRE_Pattern in a text file

Tags: python, text

I want to search for last occurence of a pattern "frame(some variable number)())" like **frame1(), frame2(), frame3()**.... (it is not exactly a string). I'm interested in getting the variable number which will keep increasing with every occurence.

i did it by using this code and **getting correct answer** but i want more efficient solution.

`regex = re.compile('frame*[0-9]*\(\)')
 NoOfFrames = len(regex.findall(textfile))`

But i think there may be more efficient way of finding it rather than listing all the occurrences and then counting it. like if we can start from last line of text file then the first occurence will be the answer. I also tried using this

`m =  mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
  i = m.rfind(regex)   # search for last occurrence of 'word'
  print(i)
  m.seek(i)             # seek to the location
  line = m.readline()   # read to the end of the line
  print(line)`

but this will not work because what i'm searching is not exactly a string. My text file is pretty big like in gigabytes and more efficient solution will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample string?

Comment: frame1(), frame2(), frame3()......frame205(), frame206()... like that. I don't know where it will end and thats why i want last occurence so that i can find out what is the last number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got its answer. we can use **regex** module which have method for backward search of patterns.

`with open('a.txt', 'r') as file:
    textfile = file.read()
 output = regex.search(r"(?r)frame*[0-9]*\(\)", textfile)
 print(output.group(0))`

This will find first occurence of **frame*[0-9]*()** from backward and output will be in _regex.Match format. To convert it into string, we can use output.group(0).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$` symbol to match the end of string ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JFajnj/2)):

```
data = '''frame1() text
frame2() text text
text frame3()
another text'''

import re

print(re.findall(r'.*frame([0-9]+)\(\).*?$', data, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Prints:

```
['3']
```

Comment: i don't know where that series will end. then how will you define data?

Comment: @vikram Then how do you know what frame is last if you don't know when the data ends?

Comment: That's what i want. see my solution. by finding length of all the occurences, we can get the final number. but i want more efficient solution than this.